# The urllib package is not available in python3

Tags: python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vEZQ.png)
The Python I use is version 3.8 and I'm writing a pycharm editor.
I want to use a urllib package,
but I can't use it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9AtW.png)
It's a package that's installed by default,
so why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your package name should not be the name of the library.

Rename your package to avoid interference .

for example:[image: this]

Comment: I solved this problem with your answer. Thank you so much. For this problem, I was looking at various options for an hour.